# Build up Richfaces4 and Primefaces3.5 but seems jQuery got conflict

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces

I was using the Richfaces4,
everything looks good.
But just right after I add following line to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
    <version>3.5</version>  
</dependency>
```

The following error shows up when I tried to login,
Seems the "Richfaces" and "jQuery" not been include/import to my server?

```
 $ is not a function
    [Break On This Error]   

    </div><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {

    home.seam (line 93)
    RichFaces is not defined
    [Break On This Error]   

    ...="display: none;"><script type="text/javascript">checkUpTime=function() 
    {RichFace...
```

Comment: You will have conflict here as both richfaces and primefaces use many common library

Comment: Is that possible to use both of them? because they have some different component but I need them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now solved in Primefaces 3.5.1. This was marked as [issue 5219](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5219). To see the change in PrimeFaces source, check [revision 8796](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/detail?r=8796).

Comment: Thanks! Just want to konw ... when can I get 3.5.1 via Maven dependency?

Answer (score 0):

use `jQuery.noConflict()` because you are have jQuery which conflicting with other library.

> **Description:** Relinquish jQuery's control of the `$` variable.
>
> Many JavaScript libraries use `$` as a function or variable name, just as `jQuery` does. In `jQuery's` case, `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`, so all functionality is available without using `$`. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside `jQuery`, return control of `$` back to the other library with a call to `$.noConflict()`. Old references of `$` are saved during `jQuery` initialization; `noConflict()` simply restores them.

#### **[Read More](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**

**Example**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
   
// Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery("div").hide();
});
```

**OR**

```
var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();

// Use jQuery via $jQ(...)
$jQ(document).ready(function()

{
    $jQ("div").hide();
});
```

Use the following technique, which allows us to use `$` inside of a block of code without overwriting `$`:

```
(function($) { /* some code that uses $ */ })(jQuery)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I already tried that, seems there were some other issue.